# Why do I have so many errors after converting my Website to a Web Application Project in Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I have a web project with dirty DLL files (as was explained to me by my friend when I showed him the following error I'm getting on breakpoints)

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. A copy of Default.aspx.vb was found in App_Web_c3jziwim.dll (Server-side symbols), but the current source code is different from the version built into App_Web_c3jziwim.dll(Server-side symbols).

Because it was a Website, I couldn't `Build -> Clean Solution` so I found [this page that explains how to convert the Website to a Web Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476(v=vs.100).aspx).

Now I have [this enormous list of errors](http://pastebin.com/vSWX8JRa)

Here's a sample of the top 5 errors on my list:

> Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types.
>   Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types.
>   Type 'SmartPeepDAL.SmartPeepManager' is not defined.
>   Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types.
>   Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types.

I have no idea what problem has occurred or how to deal with it. Feeling a lot overwhelmed right now so if anyone can help, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is because the convert to web application functionality is pretty terrible.

Long answer (not a VB guy) the errors you listed are just bad event handler attachments (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/32787dt6.aspx). Looking at the page tag AutoEventWireUp may be of help with that (http://forums.asp.net/t/932513.aspx?What+is+AutoEventWireup+)

Now I assume that you have a stack of other errors too (pretty normal with this kind of conversion) the ones I always had an issue with are

A) namespaces - because websites don't really have namespaces but web apps do you probably need to add them all over the place.

B)Codebehind vs CodeFile - I always forget which is which but generally when doing a site to app conversion I have always had to change it from the one it already has to use the other tag name instead.

Also this "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. A copy of Default.aspx.vb was found in App_Web_c3jziwim.dll (Server-side symbols), but the current source code is different from the version built into App_Web_c3jziwim.dll(Server-side symbols)." just means that you are running a debug on a build that does not match the current source code you have (build failed and ran previous?)

Comment: As to the DLL issue, it always builds new when I debug so I can't see how that can happen...

Comment: If you launch the build and something fails it can show a prompt that says something like "Debug previous version" which could cause that situation. There is a setting for it buried in Visual Studio somewhere. One easy way to check is the manually delete everything in the bin folder and see what happens at debug then.

Comment: Check under 
Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run -> On Run, when build or deployment errors occur

and

Tools->Options->Debugging->Require source files to exactly match the original version

Answer (score 0):

Take it piece by piece, solve the simple problems first. Part of refactoring code is renaming and or adding needed code. If you can eliminate code that does not reference anything much and that you do not really need that will make it easier too.

I find that removing code, helps clean up errors when upgrading a project or migrating it to something else.

Here's information about the `WithEvents`, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/32787dt6.aspx

`WithEvents` is basically same as `Handles`

It's used as a declaration, so you have to use them to declare events in your code. So make sure the WithEvents is declaring your events (and are handle correctly):

```
Dim WithEvents EventsToRaiseClass as new EventClass
```